# Parse.com - modify all the users in background job .each() doesn't work with order and .find() finishes too fast

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to get all the user data, and sort them descending by Age, then modify the age for everyone. but when i use `query.find()`, it finishes too fast. Only top 2 or 3 users age would be saved correctly. Then i try to use `query.each()`, but it doesn't work with descending order.

Here are the codes i have when using query.each(), if i don't order them, it will save all the users correctly, but i need to order them and change their age based on the order.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("ChangeUserAge", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var counter = 0;
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.descending("age, name");
    query.each(function(user) {
        counter += 1;
        user.set("age", counter);
            return user.save();
    }).then(function() {
        // Set the job's success status
        status.success("ChangeUserAge completed successfully.");
    }, function(error) {
        // Set the job's error status
        status.error("ChangeUserAge went wrong.");
  });
});
```

and here are the codes i have when using query.find(), which the problem is that finishes too fast. only 2 or 3 users saved correctly.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("RankingAllUserBasedOnDiamonds", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.descending("age, name");
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
        {
            var user = users[i];
            user.set("age", i+1);
            user.save();
        }
    }).then(function() {
         // Set the job's success status
             status.success("ChangeUserAge completed successfully.");
    }, function(error) {
        // Set the job's error status
            status.error("ChangeUserAge went wrong.");
     });
});
```

Comment: will be tough to do if the order matters.. a find can only return 1000 records, and each can't order.

Comment: the issue with your find (if < 1000 total objects) is that you need to put the promises returned by the save in an array, and return that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a couple of hours researches and testing. finally find out a way to update all object in .find(). it's `Parse.Object.saveAll`. I pushed all the object i need to update into an array, then call the saveAll with a success and error block.

but Like Fosco said, only first 1000 record got returned, so i have run the background job manually for several times with a parameter of start index.

here is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("RankingAllUserBasedOnDiamonds", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
        var usersToSave= [];
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        query.descending("age, name");
        query.find().then(function(results) {
            for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
            {
                var user = users[i];
                user.set("age", i+1);
                usersToSave.push(user);
            }
        }).then(function() {
          Parse.Object.saveAll(usersToSave, {
            success: function(list) {
                // All the objects were saved.
                if (status) {
                    status.success("Update completed successfully.");
                };
                console.log("saveInBackground success");
            }, error: function(model, error) {
                // An error occurred while saving one of the objects.
                if (status) {
                    status.error(error);
                };
                console.log("saveInBackground error: " + error.message);
            });
        }, function(error) {
            // Set the job's error status
            status.error("ChangeUserAge went wrong.");
        });
});
```

Hope that can help someone has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have less than 1,000 users, you can use promises to wait till they finish saving before ending the job:

```
query.find().then(function(results) {
    var promises = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
    {
        var user = users[i];
        user.set("age", i+1);
        promises.push(user.save());
    }
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
}).then(function() {
     // Set the job's success status
         status.success("ChangeUserAge completed successfully.");
}, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
        status.error("ChangeUserAge went wrong.");
});
```

Comment: Hi @Fosco, do you have any idea how to do that if I have more than 1000 records?

Comment: you can set query.limit(1000) and then perform an additional query with query.skip(1000), etc up to 10,000 records.  beyond that skip is not supported.